# how to send post request in python for this curl command

Tags: python, curl, browserstack

how to send a POST request in python equivalent with this curl command

```
curl -u "YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_ACCESS_KEY" \
-X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload" \
-F "url=https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk"
```

I tried code below:

```
resp=requests.post(URL,headers= 
    {'YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'},
  data=https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk")
```

and its not working.

I don't know how to send this line `"url=https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk"` in POST request.
"url=https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk" this is the public url of apk.
and want to upload at this url "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload"

And after applying answer from below, I find the solution
Thank you Everyone.
Answer is -

import urllib.request

#file will download in current working directory with name app-release.apk
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk', 'app-release.apk')

test_file = open("app-release.apk", "rb")

URL = 'https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload'
response = requests.post(URL, files={'file': test_file, }, auth=('YOUR_USERNAME', 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'))

Comment: You should use `requests` to do request like that in python

Comment: resp=requests.post(URL,headers={'YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'},data=https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk")
Yes I use Requests module with above code and its not working. but I don't know how to send  "url=https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk" this line as parameter or else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And The answer of the solution, That is work for me is

```
import urllib.request

#file will download in current working directory with name app-release.apk 

urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk', 'app-release.apk')

test_file = open("app-release.apk", "rb")

URL = 'https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload' response = requests.post(URL, files={'file': test_file, }, auth=('YOUR_USERNAME', 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)

You can do like this :

```
import requests

files = { 'file': ('url=https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk', 
open('url=https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/sample-apps/android/WikipediaSample.apk', 
'rb')),}
URL = 'https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload'
response = requests.post(URL, files=files, auth=('YOUR_USERNAME', 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'))
print (response.text)
```

It should work fine now.

Comment: its give error- TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @UddhavRaut, test again and let me know if your problem is solved

Comment: sorry, but giving error - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: Try to enter the good path of apk file

Comment: when I try with curl, then it works fine.

Comment: Try to download the file in your local and after try to execute again the code.